# Some intuition about weak topology

Tags: general-topology, weak-convergence, topological-vector-spaces, weak-topology

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological vector space with continuous dual $X^*$. "The weak topology" on $X$ is the weakest/coarsest topology under which every element of $X^*$ remains continuous on $X$.

I want to check if I'm understanding this right. For $f\in X^*$ to be continuous wrt a topology, does this mean: for every open $\epsilon$-ball $B_\epsilon(x)$ in that topology, $\epsilon \downarrow 0$ implies $f(x) - f(y) \downarrow 0$ for every $y\in B_\epsilon(x)$ and for every $f\in X^*$?

I am also confused because weaker/coarser topologies have *fewer* balls than a stronger topology. Which is why convergence in the weak topology is a weaker statement than convergence in a strong topology. But wouldn't this mean that continuity of $f\in X^*$ is a weaker statement in the weak topology? (I.e. why should functions be ``less likely" to be continuous in the weak topology?)

Similarly, if a set is compact in a stronger topology, does this imply it is compact in a weaker topology or vice versa?

Comment: What's an open $\varepsilon$-ball? Are you assuming that the weak topology is induced by a metric?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes I guess so! This is mostly because I'm not sure how to define convergence in smaller balls for general topologies

Comment: There are *no* balls in a general topological space. And the weak topology is *not* induced by a metric.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Right, so how do we state the continuity of $f\in X^*$ in this case?

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology
You shouldn't think of this as balls and metrics. Instead, think of it as the topology that only keeps the information you want as open sets. That is to say, the opens are precisely those that make the linear functionals continuous, and not one more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The weak topology on $X$ is the weakest topology such that every $\varphi\in X^*$ is continuous. That is, it's the topology whose open sets (other than $\emptyset$) are unions of sets of the form$$\varphi_1^{-1}(A_1)\cap\varphi_2^{-1}(A_2)\cap\ldots\cap\varphi_n^{-1}(A_n),$$with each $\varphi_k$ in $X^*$ and where each $A_k$ is an open subset of $\Bbb R$. So, it has the minimum amount of open sets such that each $\varphi\in X^*$ is continuous. Since this topology is weaker than $\tau$, every continuous function defined on $X$ which is continuous with respect to the weak topology is also continuous with respect to $\tau$, but this is not necessarily true in the reverse direction.

Comment: Thank you! "Since this topology is weaker than $\tau$, every continuous function on $X$ which is continuous wrt the weak topology is also continuous wrt $\tau$." Is this because there are fewer open sets in the weak topology, so that the definition of "continuous function" is now less restrictive?

Comment: Is this true for other properties like compactness/convergence? I.e. property holds in weak topology implies it also holds in stronger topology?

Comment: That depends upon the property. But, for instance, if a space is compact, then it remains compact if you replace its topology by a weaker one.

Comment: Do we mean $\varphi_k^{-1}(A_k)$ here?

Comment: @no-one Yes! I can't believe that this went unnoticed for all these years. I've edited my answer. Thank you.