# Definition of weak convergence

Tags: general-topology, banach-spaces, weak-convergence, dual-spaces, weak-topology

**Weak convergence came up in my PDE class and I'm trying to understand it even though I lack background in topology and functional analysis. Please check if my understanding is correct.**

**Definition**: Let $X$ be a real Banach space with norm $\left\lVert . \right\lVert_{X}.$ A sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges weakly to $x \in X,$ if for all continuous linear functionals $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x_n) \rightarrow f(x).$

**Question: Why is this equivalent to convergence in the weak topology?**

$\bullet$ Weak topology: The coarsest topology so that all continuous linear functionals on $X$ are still continuous. Note that we started with some topology on $X$ with respect to which we identify the linear continuous functionals. In a Banach space, we start with the norm-induced topology **(Please confirm if my understanding is correct, this is not explicitly stated in my course but I guess it is obvious)**.

$\bullet$ Convergence wrt a topology $\mathcal T$ on $X$: $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset X$ converges to $x \in X,$ if for every open set $\mathcal O \in \mathcal T,$ such that $x \in \mathcal O,$ there is $N \in \mathbb{N},$ so that $x_n \in \mathcal O$ $ \forall n \geq N.$

**Is my intuition below correct?**

The weak topology consists of sets $(\phi_{1})^{-1}(A_1), ..., (\phi_{n})^{-1}(A_n),$ where $\phi_{k}$ is a linear continuous functional and $A_k$ an open set in $\mathbb{R}.$ (**see link at the end of my post**) If $x_n$ converges to $x$ wrt to the weak topology, then for each set of the above form, if $x \in (\phi_{1})^{-1}(A_1), ..., (\phi_{n})^{-1}(A_n),$ $x_n \in (\phi_{1})^{-1}(A_1), ..., (\phi_{n})^{-1}(A_n) \forall n \geq N$ for some $N \in \mathbb{N}.$ Using the definition of preimage, it means that $ \phi_{j}(x) \in A_j $ for some $j \in [n]$ implies that $\phi_{j}(x_n) \in A_j \forall n$ large enough. And we would have to do this for every single continuous linear functional. That's why the convergence wrt to the weak topology amounts to the definition I started with.

Is this intuition correct?

[Some intuition about weak topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4290243/some-intuition-about-weak-topology) - Was useful for understanding the weak topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote your question, keeping and adjusting the correct statements, and adding a paragraph and Proposition.

**Definition**: Let $X$ be a real Banach space with norm $\left\lVert . \right\lVert_{X}.$ A sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges weakly to $x \in X,$ if for each continuous linear functional $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, the sequence $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x).$

$\bullet$ Weak topology: The coarsest topology so that all continuous linear functionals on $X$ are still continuous. Note that we started with some topology on $X$ with respect to which we identify the linear continuous functionals. In a Banach space, we start with the norm-induced topology.

It is easy to check that the weak topology has a *subbase* consisting of sets $f^{-1}(A)$, where $f:X\to \mathbb R$ is a continuous linear functional and $A$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

$\bullet$ Convergence wrt a topology $\mathcal T$ on $X$: a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of points of $X$ converges to $x \in X,$ if for every open set $\mathcal O \in \mathcal T,$ such that $x \in \mathcal O,$ there is $N \in \mathbb{N},$ so that $x_n \in \mathcal O$ $ \forall n \geq N.$

**Proposition.** Let $X$ be a Banach space, $x\in X$ be any point, and $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be any sequence of points of $X$. Then $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $x$ in the weak topology $\mathcal T$ on $X$ iff $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ weakly converges to $x$.

*Proof.*

$(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose that the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to the point $x$ in the weak topology on $X$. Let $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be any continuous linear functional. Let $A$ be any neighborhood of the point $f(x)$  in $\mathbb R$. Then $f^{-1}(A)\in\mathcal T$, so there exists
$N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n \in f^{-1}(A)$ for each natural $n\ge N$. Therefore $f(x_n)\in A$ for each $n\ge N$. It follows that the sequence $(f(x_n))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to the point $f(x)$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose that the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ weakly converges to the point $x$.
Let $B\in\mathcal T$ be any neighborhood of the point $x$. There exist a natural number $K$ and for each
$k\in\{1,\dots,K\}$ open set $A_k\in\mathbb R$ and a continuous linear functional $f_k:X\to\mathbb R$ such that $x\in\bigcap_{k=1}^K f^{-1}_k(A_k)\subset B$. Let $k\in\{1,\dots,K\}$ be any number. Since the sequence $(f_k(x_n))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $f_k(x)$, there exists $N_k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f_k(x_n)\in A_k$ for each natural $n\ge N_k$. Put $N=\max\{N_k:k\in\{1,\dots,K\}\}$. Let $n\ge N$ be any natural number and $k\in\{1,\dots,K\}$ be any number. Then $f_k(x_n)\in A_k$. It follows that $x_n\in \bigcap_{k=1}^K f^{-1}_k(A_k)\subset B$. Therefore the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to the point $x$ in the weak topology of the space $X$. $\square$

Comment: Thank you very much, this is spot on. I edited your answer to correct $k$ to $K$ in a few places, so the element $k$ varies between $1$ and $K$ and the distinction between element index and the natural number $K$ is clear.

Comment: @Len Thank you for your kind words and correcting my misprints. I am sorry for them.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give a long and thorough justification so give it a good read. Enjoy!

For a good reference to what I am doing, consider the chapter on weak topology in the book [Functional Analysis By S.Kesavan](https://bookstore.ams.org/view?ProductCode=HIN/84).

[Here is a lecture series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z6-EBVC-LGg&list=PLyqSpQzTE6M8mjwWBz0vXpmJQwR46JIdS&index=27&ab_channel=NPTEL-NOCIITM) to accompany the book by the author. I have specifically linked the video on weak topology.

Suppose you have a collection of functions $(f_{i})_{i\in I}$ from a topological space $(X,\tau)\to (Y,\Omega)$ (note that the functions need not be cts wrt $\tau$) , then, the coarsest topology on $X$  which makes $f_{i}$ cts for each $i$ is the topology generated by the following subbasis $S$. ( $I$ is some indexing set)

Let $S=\{f_{i}^{-1}(U):i\in I,U\in\Omega\,\}$. Note that this is the collection of inverse images where $i$ and $U$ varies over all possible indices and open sets in $Y$ respectively.

Then denote by $\mathcal{B}$ to be the collection of all possible finite intersections of members of $S$. i.e. $\mathcal{B}=\{\cap_{j=1}^{n}A_{i_{j}}:i_{j}\in I, A_{i_{j}}\in S, n\in\Bbb{N}\}$. Then $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for the coarsest topology which makes all $f_{i}$ continuous from $X$ to $(Y,\Omega)$.

Now if $Y=\Bbb{R}$ with usual topology, you can just consider $U$ to be open intervals $(a,b)$ and form the collection $S$ like that.

I'll define the weak topology for a Normed Vector space now. If you play with the definitions for a while, you can see why the definition below and the one above are equivalent.

> So in particular, given a normed vector space $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ and
> bounded linear functionals  $f\in X^{*}$, the coarsest topology which
> will make them continuous has the basis of sets of the form
> $\bigg\{U_{x,\epsilon, f_{1},...,f_{n}}:x\in X, f_{1},...,f_{n}\in X^{*},n\in\Bbb{N}\bigg\}$ (bear with me with the notation. It's only
> for more clarity) such that $U_{x,\epsilon, f_{1},...,f_{n}}=\{y\in X:
>  |f_{i}(x)-f_{i}(y)|<\epsilon\}$.

That is, $U_{x,\epsilon, f_{1},...,f_{n}}$ consists of elements $y$ of $X$ such that for each $f_{i}$, $f_{i}(y)$ is within $\epsilon$ distance from $f_{i}(x)$.

Now here, a minor justification has to be made as to why we are considering a single $\epsilon$ rather than $\epsilon_{1},...,\epsilon_{n}$ going with our definition of $\mathcal{B}$. The reason is that we might as well choose the smallest of those $\epsilon_{i}$'s to be $\epsilon$ and use this to make our life easier.

> So a good thing to remember for you is that a "typical" (basic) open
> set of the weak topology is of the form $U_{x,\epsilon,
>  f_{1},...,f_{n}}$.

So now, to your question, why does convergence in weak topology mean convergence of $f(x_{n})\to f(x)$ for each $f\in X^{*}$.

First, we show the forward direction. Let $x_{n}\to x$ in the topology as we defined above with the basis $\mathcal{B}$. Then let $f\in X^{*}$ be a fixed element. We wish to show $f(x_{n})\to f(x)$. But you see that this is easy now.

Consider $\varepsilon>0$ to be arbitrary, and consider $U_{x,f,\varepsilon}$ which by definition is a basic open (or rather subbasic open) neighbourhood of $x$ in the weak topology. Then, by definition of convergence, $x_{n}\in U_{x,f,\varepsilon}$ for all $n\geq N$ for some $N$. So by definition fo $U$, you have $|f(x_{n})-f(x)|<\varepsilon$ for all $n\geq N$. Hence $f(x_{n})\to f(x)$.

Conversely, let $f(x_{n})\to f(x)$ for each $f\in X^{*}$. Then, let $W$ be an arbitrary open neighbourhood of $x$ in the weak topology. By definition of basis, there exists a basic open set $U_{x,r, f_{1},...,f_{n}}\subseteq W$ such that $x\in U_{x,r, f_{1},...,f_{n}}$.

But $f_{i}(x_{n})\to f_{i}(x)$ for each $i$. Hence there exists a $N(r)$ such that $|f_{i}(x_{n})-f_{i}(x)|<\frac{r}{2}$ for all $n\geq N(r)$ and all $i=1,2,...n$.

But this means that $x_{n}\in U_{x,r, f_{1},...,f_{n}}$ for all $n\geq N(r)$. And hence $x_{n}\in W$ for all $n\geq N(r)$. This is precisely the definition of convergence.

Thus we have the required validation. The definitions were indeed justified and correct.

Comment: Thank your very much for this detailed answer and references! Is it necessary to use the basis of sets $U_{x,\epsilon, f_{1},...,f_{n}}$? What value does your approach with using this basis add in comparison the other answer by Alex Ravsky where the equivalent definition of the basis as a collection of inverse images is used?

Comment: The "value" is the explicit description of the basis. You can explicitly now apply the epsilon delta definition. General Set Topology and abstraction is all great and fine but this is functional "analysis" and you have to be as explicit as possible inorder to understand the subject more.  For example, when you are actually given an explicit sequence, it will be much much easier to use the "basic" open sets than the general "inverse images".  My main aim was to give you much easier and much less abstract description of the Basic "typical" open sets and show you the ease of working with it @Len

Comment: @Len Just consider $\Bbb{R}$ for example. How often do you actually use arbitrary open sets to prove or derive analytical results? You always use open intervals or even better, symmetric open neighbourhods $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ etc to make life much easier. Also if you regard a space with weak topology as a Topological Vector Space, you can spot (excercise) the relation to the Geometric Hahn Banach Theorem and separations by hyperplanes. To sum up, you now just have to remember the description of the basic open sets (like I gave which is easy imo) to essentially know all weakly open sets.